# I want to Concatenate image name as string with URL and want to show in UIImageView

Tags: swift, string-concatenation

I am trying to Concatenate Image Name as String with `URL` and also want to show that Image in `UIImageView` but not getting any simple solution.

```
let vc1 = baseUrl + passport
self.passportImg.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:"\(vc1)"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`URL` is not a `String`, it structured. 
You shouldn't just concatenate it using `String` concatenations, you should use proper methods for it:

```
let baseURL: URL = … // your url
let passport: String = "passport" // path to passport
let vc1 = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(passport) // it is still `URL`
self.passportImg.sd_setImage(with: vc1)
```